# Route to this action with different parameter MVC/JavaScript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Good morning, I'll try and explain this as clean as I can.

The page brings back info for a specific account, but some people may be on more than one account and I wish to provide functionality to switch between them.

Currently I have the route setup as:

```
{controller}/{action}/{accountcode}
```

`{accountcode}` can be empty and this is checked in the action and set to your default code.

So far I've got it working fine, so you can visit the following URLs:

```
{controller}/{action} OR {controller}/{action}/{accountcode}
```

So I set up a drop down list that gives you the list you have access to, and when selected it sends you to the URL for that specific account.

This works great when I go to `{controller}/{action}` and select, as it takes the `window.location.href` and appends the dropdown list value.

However, when you are at `{controller}/{action}/{accountcode}` where the drop down redirects to, and you select an account, it just tries to append another account code because of my shabby javascript logic.

I suppose I am looking for a way to get a URL to the current action without any parameters so I can define them myself. Here's where I'm struggling, as I can't use the Url Helper or Route Helper methods as this functionality is in the layout page, effectively meaning I need to get the action of the current page.

Here's my code hoping it provides clarity:

```
@if ((ViewBag.Accounts ?? new List<string>{"none"}).Count > 1)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("accounts", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, ViewBag.AccountCode))
}

$(function() {
   $("#accounts").change(function () {
       window.location.href = window.location.href + "/" + $(this).val();
    });
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when you are at {controller}/{action}/{accountcode} where the
>   drop down redirects to, and you select an account, it just tries to
>   append another account code because of my shabby javascript logic.

Well, you could easily fix this shabby logic by using URL helpers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $("#accounts").change(function () {
           var url = '@Url.Action(null, new { accountcode = "__code__" })';
           url = url.replace('__code__', $(this).val());
           window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

or if this is in a separate javascript file then simply embed the base url as an HTML 5 data-* attribute to your dropdown:

```
@if ((ViewBag.Accounts ?? new List<string>{"none"}).Count > 1)
{
    @Html.DropDownList(
        "accounts", 
        new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, ViewBag.AccountCode),
        data_url = Url.Action(null, new { accountcode = "__code__" })
    )
}
```

and then in your separate javascript file simply use this value:

```
$(function() {
   $("#accounts").change(function () {
       var url = $(this).data('url');
       url = url.replace('__code__', $(this).val());
       window.location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant example, thank you. I struggled with this as I didn't know you can pass null in to the Razor Url Helpers to get at the same action so I was trying to manipulate `Request.Url.Segments` in JavaScript into giving me what I wanted. All in all a 200% cleaner approach.

Comment: +1 for the `data-*` suggestion. No need to worry whether the string is escaped right.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the base URL has only the `{controller}/{action}` values.

`window.location = "/Controller/MyAction/" + $(this).val();`

or use the `Url` helper class:

`window.location = "@Url.Action("MyAction")/" + $(this).val();`

Comment: I would recommend against hardcoding urls as it is shown in both examples. I would recommend using Url helpers instead.

Comment: Cheers for the response, but the action is also unknown (needs to be dynamically found)